# How do I remove the Google Chrome notifications bell icon from the Mac OS X menu bar?

Tags: google-chrome, menu-bar

This bell icon showed up in my menu bar one day and there's no obvious way to disable it. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 347, accepted):

edit: **The option described below has been removed from Chrome. This should void the question as well as my answer.**

Old answer:

In the Chrome Menu Bar under **"Chrome -> Hide Notification Icon"** you can get rid of the bell without having to go through flags (which doesn't work/exist any more!).
It's the Option one from the bottom (I found the information in a comment on osxdaily):

[image]

Comment: This is finally starting to bubble up to the top of google searches. Original post on the product forums:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oYp5lXA3dhg%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: I found the `chrome://flags` solution a while ago, and I was miffed when it stopped working. This works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: None of the chrome://flags console worked after upgrade, but your solution sill works fine so far. Great tips.

Comment: I disabled it and now cannot enable - the hide notifications option is gone

Comment: @DataGreed it seems that the option has been removed from the UI. I'm on Chrom V 47.0.2526.106 and the options depicted in the screenshot isn't available any longer, as you noted. Not sure there is a way to get it back.

Comment: It's no longer there in Chrome 37.

Answer (score 22):

Google has buried this option in a very hard-to-find location.

1. Visit **chrome://flags/#enable-google-now** in Chrome.app
2. Visit **chrome://flags/#notification-center-tray-behavior** in Chrome.app
3. Change both settings to **Disabled**. (They're probably on Default currently.)

(NOTE: this used to be *chrome://flags/#enable-rich-notifications*)

Comment: On Chrome 36, none of these options exist.  :(

Comment: Ah, looks like in Chrome 36 there's a menu item for this!  See [SebK's answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139207/25999).

Answer (score 12):

This seems to have changed to

chrome://flags/#enable-google-now

I would make a comment instead of a new answer but I require 50 rep for that.

Comment: It's fine to provide a new answer explaining how another is outdated. Also, editing the wrong answer is best. Your call. Welcome to Ask Different!

Answer (score 4):

Chrome for OS X v35.0.1916.114, "Enable Rich Notifications Mac, Windows" has changed to "Notification Center behavior Mac" and is still located in chrome://flags

Answer (score 4):

It seems like Google Chrome after v 47.0.2526.73 no longer has the Notification center (bell).
[news link](http://myinforms.com/en/a/19996064-latest-google-chrome-for-desktop-update-removes-notification-center-android-update-coming-soon/)

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me by simply locating the file (mine was in the download folder) and deleting it. The key is to locate the incomplete file.

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions here appear to be outdated.

Good answer is available here:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?hl=en

Comment: This question was meant not to turn off notifs altogether, but just the bell icon

Answer (score -1):

For Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.114), all you have to do is click on the bell to open the dialog box and then simply click on the bell with the line through it to toggle it on and off.  It disables the notifications, but doesn't remove the bell, so it solves part of the problem, that you said there was "no easy way to disable it".

Answer (score -1):

It's easy. In Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m:

1. Go to **chrome://flags** in the address bar and uncheck the **Enable Rich Notifications Windows, Chrome OS** and **Google Now**
2. Google Updates has to be turned off (search for instructions on how to do this on OS X)
3. In the firewall block all traffic for Google Updater

Comment: that path does not exist on a Mac.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on the bell icon,
2. Click on the Settings tab,
3. Then uncheck "Google Now"